# How to show correct html with mews/purifier?

Tags: laravel, htmlpurifier

Using mews/purifier 3.4 in laravel 8 I wrote in my blade file content with table definition:

```
<div class="news-view-content">
    {!! \Purifier::clean($news->content) !!}
</div>
```

In my browser I see html code without table definition:

```
<p>2014 b</p>
<p>1112131421222324</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

If not to use \Purifier::clean method  I see html code with table definition:

```
<div class="news-view-content">
    <p>2014 b</p>
    <figure class="table">
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>14</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>24</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </figure>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

</div>
```

I opened config/purifier.php file and added 1 line with table rule under         custom_definition=>elements block :

```
<?php

return [
    'encoding'           => 'UTF-8',
    'finalize'           => true,
    'ignoreNonStrings'   => false,
    'cachePath'          => storage_path('app/purifier'),
    'cacheFileMode'      => 0755,


    'settings'      => [
        'default' => [
            'HTML.Doctype'             => 'HTML 4.01 Transitional',
            'HTML.Allowed'             => 'div,b,strong,i,em,u,a[href|title],ul,ol,li,p[style],br,span[style],img[width|height|alt|src]',
            'CSS.AllowedProperties'    => 'font,font-size,font-weight,font-style,font-family,text-decoration,padding-left,color,background-color,text-align',
            'AutoFormat.AutoParagraph' => false,
            'AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty'   => true,
        ],
        'test'    => [
            'Attr.EnableID' => 'true',
        ],
        "youtube" => [
            "HTML.SafeIframe"      => 'true',
            "URI.SafeIframeRegexp" => "%^(http://|https://|//)(www.youtube.com/embed/|player.vimeo.com/video/)%",
        ],
        'custom_definition' => [
            'id'  => 'html5-definitions',
            'rev' => 1,
            'debug' => false,
            'elements' => [
                // http://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html
                ['section', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],
                ['nav',     'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],
                ['article', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],
                ['aside',   'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],
                ['header',  'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],
                ['footer',  'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],

                // I ADDED THIS RULE
                ['table',  'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],


                // Content model actually excludes several tags, not modelled here
                ['address', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],
                ['hgroup', 'Block', 'Required: h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | h6', 'Common'],

                // http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html
                ['figure', 'Block', 'Optional: (figcaption, Flow) | (Flow, figcaption) | Flow', 'Common'],
                ['figcaption', 'Inline', 'Flow', 'Common'],

                // http://developers.whatwg.org/the-video-element.html#the-video-element
                ['video', 'Block', 'Optional: (source, Flow) | (Flow, source) | Flow', 'Common', [
                    'src' => 'URI',
                    'type' => 'Text',
                    'width' => 'Length',
                    'height' => 'Length',
                    'poster' => 'URI',
                    'preload' => 'Enum#auto,metadata,none',
                    'controls' => 'Bool',
                ]],
                ['source', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common', [
                    'src' => 'URI',
                    'type' => 'Text',
                ]],

                // http://developers.whatwg.org/text-level-semantics.html
                ['s',    'Inline', 'Inline', 'Common'],
                ['var',  'Inline', 'Inline', 'Common'],
                ['sub',  'Inline', 'Inline', 'Common'],
                ['sup',  'Inline', 'Inline', 'Common'],
                ['mark', 'Inline', 'Inline', 'Common'],
                ['wbr',  'Inline', 'Empty', 'Core'],

                // http://developers.whatwg.org/edits.html
                ['ins', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common', ['cite' => 'URI', 'datetime' => 'CDATA']],
                ['del', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common', ['cite' => 'URI', 'datetime' => 'CDATA']],
            ],
            'attributes' => [
                ['iframe', 'allowfullscreen', 'Bool'],
                ['table', 'height', 'Text'],
                ['td', 'border', 'Text'],
                ['th', 'border', 'Text'],
                ['tr', 'width', 'Text'],
                ['tr', 'height', 'Text'],
                ['tr', 'border', 'Text'],
            ],
        ],
        'custom_attributes' => [
            ['a', 'target', 'Enum#_blank,_self,_target,_top'],
        ],
        'custom_elements' => [
            ['u', 'Inline', 'Inline', 'Common'],
        ],
    ],


];
```

But after clearing the cache I still see html code :

```
<div class="news-view-content">
    <p>2014 b</p>
    1112131421222324<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Whicg rules have I to use to have rendered table html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing going on here is that your `HTML.Allowed` definition is currently this:

```
div,b,strong,i,em,u,a[href|title],ul,ol,li,p[style],br,span[style],img[width|height|alt|src]
```

It's missing `,table,tbody,tr,td,figure`.

A thing worth noting is that `figure` isn't supported by HTML Purifier out of the box, so even if you add it to the allowlist, absent the custom definitions, it would still get stripped, because HTML Purifier only allows things that it knows about (for security reasons).

Thankfully `figure` is already in your `custom_definition => elements`:

```php
                // http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html
                ['figure', 'Block', 'Optional: (figcaption, Flow) | (Flow, figcaption) | Flow', 'Common'],
```

So it should work once you add it to the allowlist.

Comment: Thank you! It works! Could you please to give a reference where these rules are described ?

Comment: The configuration of HTML Purifier is described here: http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html and the `custom_definition` part of the wrapper you're using around HTML Purifier, appears to be a Laravel-specific way to tap into http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html. Hope that helps!